# ruby on rails NameError: undefined local variable or method 'record'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, record, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am having trouble creating a correct HABTM (has_and_belongs_to_many) relation where custom SQL behaviour is required.  The idea is to have Documents which can be attached to a single Service or multiple Services, as well as those same Services having a single or many Documents attached to it.  I have created a model 'ResourceDocument' which houses the relation as opposed to a more traditional dual-id setup because there is going to be more types of things that related to Documents in the same way that Services do.

Here is the relevant portion of the Document model :

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ... etc ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :services,
                          :foreign_key => 'document_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'resource_id',
                          :join_table => 'resource_documents',
                          :insert_sql => proc {"insert into resource_documents (document_id, resource_id, type) values (#{id}, #{record.id}, 'Service')"}

 # ... etc ...

end
```

followed by the relevant portion of the Services spec (unit-test file) which is calling the HABTM relation when making an insert :

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Service do
  before do
    @org = Org.create!(:name => 'org', :asset_code => 'TRNT')
    # ... etc ...
  end

  # ... etc ...

  it "should not allow a document belonging to different org" do
    new_org = Org.create!({:name => 'another test Org'})
    document = FactoryGirl.create(:document, :org => new_org, :services => [@service])
    @service.documents << [document]
    @service.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

When I run `rspec`, this particular unit-test fails, and specifically the line of the document assignment (the FactoryGirl.create) barks and gives the error message written in the title.  What am I doing wrong here?  I am fairly new at ruby and more specifically the whole concept of having to perform `:insert_sql` on a HABTM relation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `record` in `{"insert into resource_documents (document_id, resource_id, type) values (#{id}, #{record.id}, 'Service')"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `record` is passed to `:insert_sql` as an argument, you would need to do something like:

```
:insert_sql => proc {|record| "insert into resource_documents (document_id, resource_id, type) values (#{id}, #{record.id}, 'Service')"}
```

So your code would be like:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ... etc ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :services,
                          :foreign_key => 'document_id',
                          :association_foreign_key => 'resource_id',
                          :join_table => 'resource_documents',
                          :insert_sql => proc {|record| "insert into resource_documents (document_id, resource_id, type) values (#{id}, #{record.id}, 'Service')"}

 # ... etc ...

end
```

**Edit**

From Rails 3.1 Release Notes:

> Previously :insert_sql and :delete_sql on has_and_belongs_to_many association allowed you to call ‘record’ to get the record being inserted or deleted. This is now passed as an argument to the proc.

Comment: Serge, thank you!  I have a bit more coding problems other than this, but this certainly fixed the major roadblock I was having.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to ask me about those problems, I'll help however I can.